# Reference for Stieltjes transform of measure (Sokhotski-Pemelj)

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

The Stieltjes transform of a probability measure $\mu$, supported on the real line, with $d\mu(x)=w(x)dx$ is defined as
$$S_\mu(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{d\mu(t) }{t-z}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{w(t) }{t-z}dt.$$
I know that the following holds for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$:
$$S_+(x)-S_{-}(x)=-2\pi iw(x), $$
with
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0+}S(x+i\epsilon)=S_+(x)\quad
 \text{ and }\quad
 \lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0+}S(x-i\epsilon)=S_-(x). $$
This result is known to me as the Sokhotski-Pemelj lemma, but I can't find a good reference for this theorem. When I was looking online, the best I found was [this pdf](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-540-47711-2%2F1.pdf), but I don't know what book it comes from. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a bit further, I found that the lemma is proven in this book: Boundary Value Problems by F. D. Gakhov in section I.4.2.